# On Git, how can I merge a branch and delete the temporary branch with one terminal command?

Tags: git, powershell

Error on "git merge -d featureA"

I tried the command "git merge -d featureA", because I would like to merge the branch featureA to main branch and delete the branch "featureA" with one terminal command.

The result I have is

```
error: unknown switch `d'
usage: git merge [<options>] [<commit>...]
   or: git merge --abort
   or: git merge --continue

    -n                    do not show a diffstat at the end of the merge
    --stat                show a diffstat at the end of the merge
    --summary             (synonym to --stat)
    --log[=<n>]           add (at most <n>) entries from shortlog to merge commit message
    --squash              create a single commit instead of doing a merge
    --commit              perform a commit if the merge succeeds (default)
    -e, --edit            edit message before committing
    --cleanup <mode>      how to strip spaces and #comments from message
    --ff                  allow fast-forward (default)
    --ff-only             abort if fast-forward is not possible
    --rerere-autoupdate   update the index with reused conflict resolution if possible
    --verify-signatures   verify that the named commit has a valid GPG signature
    -s, --strategy <strategy>
                          merge strategy to use
    -X, --strategy-option <option=value>
                          option for selected merge strategy
    -m, --message <message>
                          merge commit message (for a non-fast-forward merge)
    -F, --file <path>     read message from file
    --into-name <name>    use <name> instead of the real target
    -v, --verbose         be more verbose
    -q, --quiet           be more quiet
    --abort               abort the current in-progress merge
    --quit                --abort but leave index and working tree alone
    --continue            continue the current in-progress merge
    --allow-unrelated-histories
                          allow merging unrelated histories
    --progress            force progress reporting
    -S, --gpg-sign[=<key-id>]
                          GPG sign commit
    --autostash           automatically stash/stash pop before and after
    --overwrite-ignore    update ignored files (default)
    --signoff             add a Signed-off-by trailer
    --no-verify           bypass pre-merge-commit and commit-msg hooks
```

I tried

```
git merge -d featureA
```

Comment: Error seems pretty self-explanatory: the `merge` command doesn't have a `-d` flag. Run `git branch -d <branchName>` after `git merge` succeeds instead

Comment: Or set an alias that chains the two together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PowerShell has the `&&` operator which runs the second command if the first succeeds.

```
git merge featureA && git branch -d featureA
```

Comment: I think you need PowerShell 7 or higher for `&&`.